# How to compute N number of Pi

Tags: math, pi

I have found this formula for computing Pi value: [image]

But I need to compute only(for example - 1000th) number of Pi value. How I can do it with provided formula?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to compute this formula, but it returns only pure Pi value, not specific number...

Comment: Why is there a downvote? This is an interesting question.

Comment: @Ali I agree it is an interesting question, but the question does not demonstrate any research effort.  That is why I gave it a downvote.

Comment: Should probably be migrated to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a "spigot algorithm". Take a look at [1] in the section "BBP digit-extraction algorithm for pi". Good luck and have fun.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: Thanks, but how I can use it formula to find 1000th number of Pi value?

Comment: instructions are on that web page. Be aware this formula gets you the base16 hexidecimal digits. Is that what you want? Yuo cant get a single decimal digit this way.